# CakePHP 2.x theme not working

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.x

I have a problem with CakePHP (newest version) themes. I have created new theme to /app/View/Themed/Start/

and it contains default.ctp inside the Start folder.

I have edited /app/Controller/AppController.php and I placed this code inside it:

```
    class ThemeController extends AppController {
    public $theme = 'Start';
}
```

But it still uses the default layout instead of my own template. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You'll have to put the default.ctp inside the 'Layouts' folder inside your theme folder; e.g. `app/View/Themed/Start/Layouts/default.ctp` http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/themes.html

Comment: @thaJeztah quite likely - make an answer for some reputation :)

Comment: That doesn't work either, I put the default.ctp to /app/View/Themed/Start/Layouts but it still takes the layout from /app/View/Layouts/

Comment: Are you using scaffolding? Is debug enabled?

Comment: Never solved this issue. I changed to Yii framework..

Answer (score 0):

That code shouldn't be placed in AppController (Or anywhere for that matter) all you simply need to do is set the theme in AppController like this:

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    public $theme = 'Start';
```

It will then take your view files from app/View/Themed/Start